# Unable to use alias of .bash_profile in Jenkins build

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on MAC and 
I am trying to use alias created on my MAC ~/.bash_profile in jenkin build.
Is it possible?
I have tried using expand_aliases option as well but not luck.
I am running my jenkins from custom workspace  ie /Users/user1.

Here is the output of jenkins console.`Started by user admin
Building in workspace /Users/user1

```
[user1] $ /bin/bash -xe /var/folders/55/fxxv86j970zcdv3gs27z4flm0000gp/T/jenkins2742750483712853243.sh
+ cd /Users/user1
+ pwd
/Users/user1
+ env
+ grep -i shell
SHELL=/bin/bash
+ source /Users/user1/.bash_profile


++ alias 'l=ls -lasrt'

+ l
/var/folders/55/fxxv86j970zcdv3gs27z4flm0000gp/T/jenkins2770891577912812441.sh: line 8: l: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
`
```

Comment: Aliases aren't expanded by default in a shell script; why not just type out `ls -lasrt` directly? Readability is a bigger concern than brevity in a script.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a big mistake. Don't add quotes like that.

```
alias 'l=ls -lasrt' is wrong.
```

Right: This will work

```
alias l='ls -lasrt' is right
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias lx='ls -CF'
```